# How to prove convergence in distribution of a normal random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> If $X_n\sim \mathfrak{N}(0;1)$ is a normal random variable. How do I show that $X_n\Rightarrow X$ in distribution where also $X\in \mathfrak{N}(0;1)$?

I somehow have no idea how  to show this, I only know that if $X\sim \mathfrak{N}(0;1)$ then $$\Phi_X(x)=\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$$

Could maybe someone explain me this because this is new to me and I'm a bit confused.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems trivial.  All the $X_n$ have exactly the same distribution, so the sequence converges in distribution to that same distribution (and the characteristic function never changes).

Comment: @Henry Could you maybe show this explicitly because I don't know how to handle $\lim_n \Phi_{X_n}(x)$ because I somehow don't have a $n$ in the integral. And If the characteristic function never changes does this imply that they have the same distribution?

Comment: @Henry sorry for the stupid question but I'm really confused with this convergence in distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of convergence in distribution is that the distribution of $X_n$ (as $n \to \infty)$ approximates the desired distribution of $X$. It is like the sequence of cdf's of $X_n$ converges to the cdf of $X$.

In your case, distribution of $X_n$ for all $n$ and the distribution of $X$ is the same, so the sequence converges to $X$ in distribution since the distribution does not change (i.e. the sequence of the cdfs of $X_n$ is actually constant).

Comment: Why do I know that the distribution of $X$ is the same as the one of all $X_n$

Comment: @Wave, All the $X_n$'s have the standard normal distribution, which is the hypothesis of your problem :)